# Combine a C# project into a single class file

Tags: c#

Are there any tools or methods for combining an entire c# class library (project) into a single class file.

My primary reason for doing this is because I would like to use some c# open source libraries but each library I add results in another project and another dll to manage and distribute.

If there was an automated way to merge / combine the files then I would still be able to compare the source and look for changes.

In addition, I suspect that if I modified all classes to be "internal" while combining then the compiler could discard everything I don't actually use.

The intention is to then use that class file directly inside my larger project.

```
My Project
  Open Source Pieces
    BarcodeLibrary.cs
    CryptoLibrary.cs
    etc ...
```

This was supposed to be a simple HowTo question but since I need to provide a philosophical justification...

The comments about using nuget are valid and applicable but I have had multiple experiences with projects built by pulling in a number of "internet" hosted libraries.  Those experiences have NOT been joyous to say the least.  I now prefer to take a much more hands on and selective approach when using external libraries and code.

Regarding Source Control.  A single well structured file for a single project that you are never going to edit (except for updates) would help to reduce the clutter in a project instead of creating extra problems.

Update: I built what I needed and am testing the results, hope to return with a tool and example.

Comment: Combine the whole source code into a single C# file? Are you serious?

Comment: While it is technically possible to have more than one class in one .cs file, I do see a problem when it comes to namespaces. Not to speak of the hell you would be putting yourself into.

Comment: `My primary reason for doing this is because I would like to use some c# open source libraries but each library I add results in another project and another dll to manage and distribute.`  How in the world are you using these libraries?  You're supposed to pull in their DLL artifacts, not their entire source code.  Nuget dependencies manage this very nicely, and without creating another project per dependency.

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295) where Y is really terrible idea. Would you like to solve X instead?

Comment: Amy's got a point. Do you add those as projects to your solution and compile them along with it? You should only reference the dll. Or even better: Use nuget, which automates nearly anything about 3rd party dependencies for you.

Comment: Even if it were a good idea to merge all these libraries into one *project* (which it isn't), it's absolutely normal for a single project, compiling to a single binary, to have more than one *source file* in it. Hundreds of .cs files, one .dll or .exe. Come down off the ledge, Harry. You don't have to do this. Or anything remotely like this.

Comment: A single C# project already produces a single "class file".  You are probably asking for ILMerge.  Or the kind of bundling that Windows users expect, a single file called setup.exe

Comment: Question updated with philosophical justification.

Comment: "I have had multiple experiences with projects built by pulling in a number of "internet" hosted libraries" - I really do not get your point here. The source of the project is the same, if you are using nuget, download a precompiled binary (dll) or pull the source tree into your solution? All you gain is a more complicated toolchain and extended build time.

Comment: @AnthonyVO What issues did you run into using Nuget?  I've used Nuget for years with multiple large projects in a professional setting and I haven't run into any problems so significant that I abandoned Nuget entirely.  I still feel quite strongly that this is still an XY problem, and not merely a difference of philosophy.  The idea of combining hundreds of source files together into one gigantic file makes me cringe inwardly.

Comment: They [taught us about this one in school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_Was_an_Old_Lady_Who_Swallowed_a_Fly#Lyrics).

Comment: @Amy, Not necessarily Nuget.  Experience was with Android development.  The biggest issues were packages changing unexpectedly, including on the build server.  To easy for a developer to purposely or accidentally trigger a "update all dependencies" resulting in a great big hairy broken mess if not caught on time.

Comment: If you're using Git, using some hooks, in particular the `pre-commit` hook, to prevent changes to the package dependencies would be a better solution than abandoning packaged dependencies entirely.  Other Git options are available, such as `skip-worktree`, though I don't think that fits your use-case.  Or use pull requests to manage your code, and reject requests that include changes to the dependencies.

Comment: @Fildor, I don't like DLLs, because they are dlls that I have to ship, and they hide the source so I don't really know what changed.  I don't like some of the source trees because they are unnecessarily complex, a 1000 lines of actual code spread over 50 files.  I was tempted, but I am not going to give an example.   Merging that into a single well structured *.cs file is a win for me.

Answer (score 3):

I would seriously recommend against doing such a thing. It makes code navigation a nightmare. Also your version control system is probably not going to like this. If you are worried about forgetting dependencies between your projects, I suggest using build tooling and dependency managers like NuGet to get these under control.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Costura.Fody to bundle all your assemblies into one.  I think this is the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: That is a great find.   Thanks.